# make one side of button curved from middle

Tags: android, android-drawable

i want to create a button like this :

[image]

as you see the button is curved from the middle to the inside.
i have tries something like this but it's far from what i want.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="2"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <size
                android:width="50dp"
                android:height="50dp" />

            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

how can i do this ?
 is it possible to create it with **xml drawables** ?

Comment: It might be a good idea to show what the output of your code gives! Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you... try...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
            <size android:height="100dp"
                android:width="200dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:right="160dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp"
        android:left="-90dp">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:innerRadius="2dp"

            android:shape="oval"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <size
                android:width="50dp"
                android:height="50dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Mark it as correct answer if it is worked for you. It will save others time.

Comment: thank you . it works . is it possible to make color of curved area transparent ?

Comment: Sure, just change the color here to transparent in this line `<solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>`, Transparent color code is #00FFFFFF